# Problem maximizing a function

Tags: constraint, maximize

I have a problem maximizing the following function:

```
Maximize[
  {
    {1/(1 + γ) - 4^-ϵ A ((a^2 (β - b γ))/(b (b + β) (1 + γ)))^ϵ}, 
    γ >= 0, a > 0, b > 0, β > 0, A > 0
  }, γ
]
```

I would like to have a range of solutions depending on all of these variables, but it seems that the epsilon is causing troubles.
I also tried to directly take the first order condition and then solves it when it is equal to 0. But it does not work neither:

```
dPiCFdγ = FullSimplify[D[{1/(1 + γ) - 4^-ϵ A ((a^2 (β - b γ))/(b (b + β) (1 + γ)))^ϵ}, γ]]
```

and then:

```
Sol2 = FullSimplify[Solve[dPiCFdγ == 0, γ]]
```

The only thing that works is when I set a value for epsilon (2 for instance).

Could you help me please?

Comment: 1) You have one extra layer of braces in Maximize; you don't need to enclose the function itself in braces; 2) taking the derivative and solving for its zero seems to give an expression for gamma: what is wrong with that?

Comment: Dear MarcoB, thanks for your answer. In fact, when I take the derivative and look and try to solve it for gamma, I get this: "Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information."

Comment: @blo Yes, but that's a warning rather than an error. Have you tried using Reduce instead of Solve, as it suggests?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Yes, I did try Reduce instead of Solve. It did not work